# Restore SPFarm from live to test

Tags: 2013, administration, backup, restore

I took a farm backup for our live sharepoint server 2013 enterprise :-

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \\fileserver100\intranetbackup\FarmBackUp\ -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force
```

now i want to restore this farm to our test sharepoint server which have the same farm build number. but i am not sure how i can do so? last time i needed to do a restore for the farm was when i restored the farm inside the live server (where i took the backup-spfamr on),, but i am not sure how i can restore the farm on different server?

Answer (score 1):

just use `Restore-SPfarm` PowerShell command for SharePoint. Documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/restore-spfarm?view=sharepoint-ps).

Content Databases you can do:

1. backup all databases in PRODUCTION instance on SQL server
2. copy them to TEST instance and attach them here
3. content databases you can mount to TEST SharePoint with [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/attach-or-detach-content-databases)

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: but per my knowledge the `Restore-SPfarm` command will try to restore the backup files inside the same environment where the `Backup-SPfarm` was done, but in my case i want to force it to do the Restore on different server,, so how i can do so? for ur second point, i know that i can do a backup for the sql server, but in my case i am doing a full `SPFarm-Backup` to ease things, and as u know the `Backup-SPFarm` already do SQL server backups for us..

Comment: it depends on when you are running this commandlet Restore-SPfarm, you can use it for create a copy of prod environment to test

Comment: I have moved the backup files to the test server C drive and i will be running the `Restore-SPfarm` on the test server also..

Comment: yes it should works, how's your output?

Answer (score 0):

I never use Backup-SPFarm. For best result re-build your farm (to keep things in line I use SPDocKit to create AutoSPInstaller file, then I update it with new server names for QA farm but with some work you can get the necessary config manually or with PowerShell) after new farm is deployed I install all custom solutions and attach backup content databases to it.

Comment: there are many ways to do the farm backup/restore,, but my question is about `Restore-SPFarm` command...